# Qt DockWidget with Direct3D Widget

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, direct3d

I have the following setup within Qt

```
class Editor : public QMainWindow {
...
};
```

Within this Editor class, i create a SceneWidget which is defined as

```
class EditorSceneWindow : public QDockWidget {
...
};
```

Within the EditorSceneWindow i have a custom Direct3D widget defined as

```
class D3DRenderWidget : public QWidget {
...
};
```

My problem is that when the application starts up, the size of my Direct3DWidget is 100x30 (Toolbar dimensions of the DockWidget.  I know i can set the minimum width/height, however, i want the Direct3DWidget to fill the entire DockWidget.  I have tried setting numerous different combos of the QSizePolicy for the Direct3DWidget, as it is the child of the SceneWindow DockWidget.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried QDockWidget::setWidget()?

Comment: Yea, in EditorSceneWindow class, when i create the new Direct3DWidget, i call setWidget(d3dRenderWidget).